# How to pull data from one database to another database using sqlsqerver 2005

Tags: sql-server

How to pull data from one database to another database by using sqlsqerver 2005

like ..Exporting data from one and importing to the another.

Comment: What are you trying to do? We need more detail.
Are you trying to move a db to a new server, backup a db?

Comment: I want to copy data from one table to another table and these two tables are in two different databases

Comment: are those databases on the same server?

Comment: Yes they are on the same server

Answer (score 2):

Take your pick.

1. Linked Server/databases.
2. SSIS
3. Exporting data from one and importing to the another.

Comment: Exporting data from one and importing to the another.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to no-one's answers, if the DB's are both SQL Server

4) Select * into New_Table From Server.Database.Owner.Table

Comment: This is no_one's answer number 1

Comment: A little example goes a long way though, and vec doesn't state whether he's moving between servers.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments I understand that both databases are on the same server
You can simply do:

```
use YourDestinationDatabaseName;

select * into dbo.yourNewTable from YourSourceDatabase.dbo.YourSourceTable
```

and if you want to insert into table that already exists

```
use YourDestinationDatabaseName;

insert into dbo.YourDestinationTable 
select * from YourSourceDatabase.dbo.YourSourceTable
```

or more precisely:

```
use YourDestinationDatabaseName;

insert into dbo.YourDestinationTable( col1, col2, etc...) 
select 
    col1a, col2a, etc ... 
from 
    YourSourceDatabase.dbo.YourSourceTable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have VS 2005, I like this tool, because it generates t-sql: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A&displaylang=en